# how to handle button onclick action in iPhone without using interface builder?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

how to handle **button onclick action** in iPhone without using interface builder?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After you create a button write;

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Edit**

Also implement this in your .m file

```
-(void)buttonAction
{
    //your implementation
}
```

Comment: hi..i've aded addTarget functionality in my code. but stil on click of button , nothing is happening. no action is done.